# How to keep persistent server-side data available to a Google Drive sidebar?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to access objects in a persistent server-side instance of my Google Apps Script code from the sidebar HTML doc that it creates.

I'm fairly experienced in GAS, but much less experienced in web design. My over-all goal is to create an interactive side-bar that represents the internal structure of a Google Doc.

Right now it shows the structure of the document at the time that it runs, but I want to implement features like highlighting or clicking on elements in the sidebar to highlight the corresponding element in the Google doc, and/or vice versa.

I want to do this by having access to a correspondence between the IDs of the HTML elements and the GAS objects representing the Google doc elements. Constructing that correspondence when the script is first run is easy, but I don't know how to keep it around so the HTML code has access to it.

I know that you can call GAS functions from the HTML, but they won't exist in the same execution instance, so they won't have access to the correspondence.

I know that you can pass data to the HTML doc by using templates, but that would require serializing the `Document` object, or `ParagraphElement` objects, or whatever, which I want to avoid dealing with if possible. I also want those objects to maintain their connection to the actual Google doc, and as far as I understand, they wouldn't.

I know that you can access a cache, and/or document properties, but both of these also involve serializing `Document` objects.

I know that you can use triggers to call GAS functions, e.g. when the document is edited, and then access the document's UI, but (again, as far as I understand) this would require rewriting the whole sidebar HTML whenever the document is edited, which I assume would make it look janky and annoying.

How can I go about doing this? Are any of my assumptions wrong? Are there any good examples of this sort of thing out there?

Comment: I don't think you can serialize the document object. And Google docs  doesn't have a edit trigger. IMO, What you're looking for is hard, if not impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I guess it's good to hear that I'm not struggling with this for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar to this.  I wanted to keep track of parts of a document and be able to change the formatting of them from a sidebar. I wanted this to work even if the document changed.

My solution was to embed zero width (non-printing) unicode characters in the document around the pieces that I wanted to highlight. I could then use a pattern search to find the pieces that I was interested in and change font, formatting etc.

The characters I used were :

```
var ZERO_WIDTH_SPACE = '\u200B';
var ZERO_WIDTH_NON_JOINER = '\u200C';
var ZERO_WIDTH_JOINER = '\u200D';
var ZERO_WIDTH_NBSP = '\uFEFF';
```

Comment: Haha I'm actually already using exactly those characters for something else. Hooray for hacky solutions to features that should be in Google docs I guess. Unfortunately they won't work here since I need the document to be manually editable.